# Regex for repeating (similar) expressions in <input> JQuery

Tags: javascript, regex

I have an input text field with article numbers like this:

```
ABC_ABC123; AB__B2A4; ABF_323WET; ...
```

so I would like oblige the user to keep the art no. formats...

Here is my regex for this and it's working for one art number:

```
var mask1 = /^([A-Z]{2})([A-Z|_]{1})_([A-Z0-9]{0,16});$/;
```

But I want to extend it for further strings / art no

how can I solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Try `/^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z_]_[A-Za-z0-9]{0,16};(?: [A-Z]{2}[A-Z_]_[A-Za-z0-9]{0,16};)*$/`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/JUR6Y8/1).

Comment: Thanks, it works! Can you write a short explanation for me about it? I would like to accurately understand it. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your single item pattern, there is a problem with matching lowercase letters, you must add them to the character class, `[A-Z0-9]{0,16}` => `[A-Za-z0-9]{0,16}`.

The overall solution will look like

```
/^[A-Z]{2}[A-Z_]_[A-Za-z0-9]{0,16};(?: [A-Z]{2}[A-Z_]_[A-Za-z0-9]{0,16};)*$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/JUR6Y8/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z]{2}[A-Z_]_[A-Za-z0-9]{0,16};` - your item pattern:

  - `[A-Z]{2}` - two uppercase ASCII letters
  - `[A-Z_]` - an  uppercase ASCII letter or `_`
  - `_` - a `_` char
  - `[A-Za-z0-9]{0,16}` - 0 to 16 alphanumeric ASCII chars
  - `;` - a semi-colon
- `(?: [A-Z]{2}[A-Z_]_[A-Za-z0-9]{0,16};)*` - 0 or more occurrences of

  - - space (replace with `\s` to match any whitespace, `\\s` in the constructor notation)
  - `[A-Z]{2}[A-Z_]_[A-Za-z0-9]{0,16};` - the item pattern
- `$` - end of string.

In JS, you may build the pattern dynamically to make it readable:

```js
var block = "[A-Z]{2}[A-Z_]_[A-Za-z0-9]{0,16};"
var regex = new RegExp(`^${block}(?: ${block})*$`)
console.log( regex.test("ABC_abc123; AB__B2A4; ABF_323WET;") )
```

Comment: I don't want to accept lowercase letters, input style will be uppercase.

Comment: @MátéKiss You have `ABC_abc123` in your example. If you do not want to match that, you need to edit your question.

Comment: @MátéKiss Anyway, you may amend the regex at will, and with dynamic building, it becomes easier to handle.